# specific class variable value in generic method

Tags: c#

in my program I have following code:

```
 private void SetCorners<T>(T position, int width, int height)
    {
        float halfWidth = width / 2 + position.X;
        float halfHeight = height / 2 + position.Y;

        UpperLeft = new Vector2(-halfWidth, -halfHeight);
        UpperRight = new Vector2(halfWidth, -halfHeight);
        LowerLeft = new Vector2(-halfWidth, halfHeight);
        LowerRight = new Vector2(halfWidth, halfHeight);
    }
```

In which T is either `Vector2` or `Vector3` from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`. This code does not build because `T` does not contains definition of them.How to make this method works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create a wrapper class for the two structs:

```
private void SetCorners<T>(T position, int width, int height)
    where T : MyVectorWrapper
{
    float halfWidth = width / 2 + position.X;
    float halfHeight = height / 2 + position.Y;

    UpperLeft = new Vector2(-halfWidth, -halfHeight);
    UpperRight = new Vector2(halfWidth, -halfHeight);
    LowerLeft = new Vector2(-halfWidth, halfHeight);
    LowerRight = new Vector2(halfWidth, halfHeight);
}

class MyVectorWrapper
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }

    public MyVectorWrapper(dynamic vector2)
    {
        X = vector2.X;
        Y = vector2.Y;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var v2 = new Vector2(1, 2);
var v3 = new Vector3(v2, 3);
SetCorners<MyVectorWrapper>(new MyVectorWrapper(v2), width, height);
SetCorners<MyVectorWrapper>(new MyVectorWrapper(v3), width, height);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It is not type safe, it is more code for the caller to write and harder to understand

Comment: I'm just following as much as possible the request in the question. It's at the users latitude to decide which approach is best for him, isn't it? Maybe at a later time there is a need for `Vector4` support, who knows, you don't know the outer context.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no common base-class or interface that both `Vector2` and `Vector3` derive from or implement, you would create a method that takes `X` and `Y` directly and create two helper methods that call this new method:

```
private void SetCorners(Vector2 position, int width, int height)
{
    SetCorners(position.X, position.Y, width, height);
}

private void SetCorners(Vector3 position, int width, int height)
{
    SetCorners(position.X, position.Y, width, height);
}

private void SetCorners(float x, float y, int width, int height)
{
    float halfWidth = width / 2 + x;
    float halfHeight = height / 2 + y;

    UpperLeft = new Vector2(-halfWidth, -halfHeight);
    UpperRight = new Vector2(halfWidth, -halfHeight);
    LowerLeft = new Vector2(-halfWidth, halfHeight);
    LowerRight = new Vector2(halfWidth, halfHeight);
}
```

This allows you to not repeat yourself ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) but still support both `Vector2` and `Vector3`.

Comment: that was exactly my 1st approach :) An I will stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would then write two separate methods, one for `Vector2` and one for `Vector3`. Generally speaking you could use a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) but I think this would be a bit too artificial here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Vector2 and Vector3 have some common interface or base class but you could add a constraint to your generic method like so:

```
private void Method<T>(T bla)
  where T : BaseInterfaceOrBaseClass
{ ... }
```

Comment: I did like you you wrote."where T : Vector2,Vector3" Unfortunately are not a valid constraint.Both inherit from same interface IEquatable<T> but it doesn't implements neither X or Y.

Comment: I see, then the explicit method taking two int parameters (for X and Y) seem to be the only option.